# Why I customize the button on the cell click event in the cell can not receive

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have customized a View like this :

```
 #import "LWView.h"
    @implementation LWView
    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y , frame.size.width, frame.size.height)]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
        [btn setTitle:@"点我" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:nil action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self addSubview:btn];
    }
    return self;
    }
    @end
```

Yes, I set the target to nil Because I want to add this view to my custom cell And i want my cell to implement this SEL，this is the custom cell code :

```
 #import "LWTableViewCell.h"
    #import "LWView.h"
    @implementation LWTableViewCell
    - (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        LWView *lwView = [[LWView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:lwView];
    }
    return self;
}

      - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

    - (void)click {
    NSLog(@"U click me!");
     }
    @end
```

I implemented the use of custom cell in tableview，But when I click on this button, the SEL in the cell is not called，Guys, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

In your cell implementation,you implement the click method,but no target to call the method.so you can try with protocol delegate or block.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I think the target is nil, the system will follow the response chain to find the next level of the next level has not achieved SEL, so I realized in the cell of the SEL. But very strange, and did not call here. By the way, if the custom view and the controller and the delegate to achieve this SEL, the system will call to, I tested